# SharePoint 2016 ZDP; How do 2 seperate web front ends communicate with 1 sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sharepoint

I've been researching ZDP for SharePoint 2016, and I know there are redundant servers for the web front end / application servers depending on your logical architecture.  What I'm not understanding is how these multiple web front ends would communicate with a single sql back end.  Would they just be duplicates that point to the same sql server?

Comment: I think even when you use multiple webfronts,the user will be connected to only one server at a time,so the idea is to just to balance the load on webfront

Comment: Dylan when there are multiple WFE in picture, there is always load balancer above it to handle the request. Load balancer equally distributes the requests among no of WFEs. There is setting at load balancer level on how to handle the request : session based and other one I don't remember. In session based routing, once session is created, it will be served by one WFE till session expires. Request can land on any WFE depending on network load and Routing algo configured on load balancer.